# OrientDB graph view displays @rid

Tags: orientdb

I am following the OrientDB tutorial on https://www.udemy.com/orientdb-getting-started/learn/v4/t/lecture/1783886?start=225
When I run the query 
    select from make
On the VehicleGraphDatabase. The graph displays @rid for all entities and NOT the Vehicle Make as per the tutorial. What is required to view the graph as per the tutorial?

Comment: are the circle dashed?

Answer (score 0):

- Try and click on a node, choose the eye-symbol and a pane shows up.
- Select the cogwheel tab and configure the appearance of the nodes of the same type.
- Don't forget to save the configuration.

Hope this helps!
Ingo